# In PhpExcel library when i am assigning values to IW4 the assigned value not generatted there

Tags: phpexcel

In PhpExcel library when i am assigning values to IW4 the assigned value not generatted there

Steps:

```
 We are using The code to generate the Value to cell in PHPExcel
      **$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'cell value here');**

 When i am using it to generate value to IW4 cell the value not getting generatted

       **$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('IW4', 'cell value here');**
```

Please Help me to find the solution

Answer (score 0):

BIFF format Excel files only allow 256 columns (up to IV), OfficeOpenXML allows more.
If you set a value in a column beyond the limit, PHPExcel only knows it's invalid at the point where you save (when it knows whether you're saving as an Excel5 or Excel2007 file), Rather than trigger an exception at that point (which would be much more frustrating if it was a long running script), it silently discards the invalid columns or rows.

This is similar behaviour to Excel itself, if you open an xlsx file in an earlier version of Excel that doesn't support as many rows and columns.